# Scroll is not fluid - Jetpack Compose

Tags: gridview, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, vertical-scrolling

I've created a component that is recycled in different pages of the app. On each page, the card receives images of different sizes from the backend.

I have this box with mutable dimension:

```
@Composable
    fun BoxCardView(image: String) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .widthIn(125.dp, 325.dp)
                    .heightIn(100.dp, 200.dp)
            ){
                IMImage(
                    data = image,
                    contentDescription = "image",
                )
            }
    }
```

that is used in a LazyVerticalGrid also with mutable dimension setted in this way:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
            modifier = Modifier.heightIn(80.dp, 1100.dp),
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2) { ... }
```

By inserting the component in a column together with other components the scroll is not fluid when I get to the component I'm recycling. How can I fix?

Comment: Have you tried to test the performance on a non-debugable version? All the lazy composables usually have a problem with flickering and stuttering on builds that are debugable

Answer (score 0):

first of all check scroll performance with release build and flags

```
isDebuggable = false
isMinifyEnabled = true
```

[here is](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-should-you-always-test-compose-performance-in-release-4168dd0f2c71) long explanation why debug build can give you irrelevant results.

If the problems persist with the release build you need to check how many times your composable functions are recomposed, you can do this with the layout inspector in new versions of android studio.

If you see a large number of recompositions, then it is usually due to the calculation performed on each recomposition. however, there are no calculations in the code you provided, so I recommend that you first follow the first steps I described and edit your question with additional information if the problem persists